# On AWS Lambda, using puppeteer page.goto fails for me, with net::ERR_INSUFFICIENT_RESOURCES

Tags: aws-lambda, puppeteer, google-chrome-headless

Environment:

Puppeteer 1.2.0
Amazon Lambda 2017.03
Node.js 6.10.3

When I use page.goto to open any page (I've tried a few, including www.gov.uk) , I get this error from puppeteer debugger:

```
Sun, 18 Mar 2018 19:23:22 GMT puppeteer:session ◀ RECV
{
    "method": "Network.loadingFailed",
    "params": {
        "requestId": "814A8DEA78A42CCF39F05E9825CFEB34",
        "timestamp": 1374.512353,
        "type": "Document",
        "errorText": "net::ERR_INSUFFICIENT_RESOURCES",
        "canceled": false
    }
}
```

Even though the Lambda function is set to 1536mb. When it finally times out because of the crash, it says Max Memory Used: 166 MB

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seem to have fixed it by using a different chromium binary for lambda.

Using one from [Puppeteer Lambda Starter Kit](https://github.com/sambaiz/puppeteer-lambda-starter-kit/tree/master/chrome) seems to work